# VMWare player grabbing mouse focus

Tags: windows-7, mouse, vmware-player

I am using the newest VMWare player on a Windows 7 machine.  When I have the player open on one of my two monitors I get some weird behavior.

For instance, if the player is open on monitor 2, and I minimize firefox on monitor 1, my mouse will instantly switch to the monitor 2 and be centered within the VMWare player window.

This happens when I minimize any window after having been working in my VM.  I hope there is a setting or tweak that I am not aware of that can remedy this.

EDIT: Through more testing I have found that this only occurs when the VMWare player is full screen on either of my two monitors.

Also, I found people having the exact same issue at:
http://communities.vmware.com/message/1244913

Answer (score 1):

Although this tip is for Vista, it may still work in 7:

http://www.nordichardware.com/news,1644.html

Be careful inside the registry and dont change anything besides what the website tells you to.

Its only a minor change, you may have to restart your comptuer to experiance the effect.

Comment: This did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Ok when you get your mouse out of the VM, try minimizing the VM window. Then it should stop it from stealing the focus of other windows.

Comment: Sure, but what if I have Visual Studio full screen on my VM and then on my host I have a few windows open that I am using to help me work in Visual Studio IE: chrome, ms project, outlook, etc?

Answer (score 0):

The page @Tanner Collin originally [suggested](http://www.nordichardware.com/news,1644.html) seems to be returning 404 errors now, but I did find it in the [waybackmachine](http://web.archive.org/web/20080519145705/http://www.nordichardware.com/news,1644.html).

I also had a look for other pages detailing how to prevent windows stealing focus. There are a number out there, including these at [about.com](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsxp/ht/stealingfocus02.htm) and [howtodothings.com](http://www.howtodothings.com/computers-internet/how-to-prevent-programs-from-stealing-focus-in-windows-xp).

Also, [this forum thread](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/win98/t1024045414) is interesting, since it describes problems with applications resetting this setting.